# iPhone SDK: Preferences

Tags: iphone, preferences, lines

I wanted an entire page of text(multiple lines) in my settings similar to the one on iphone:
**settings->general settings->About->Legal**

I have not been able to do so. I tried entering title in PSGroupSpecifier, it gives me multiple lines but with a gray background. i wanted a white background. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use a UIWebView and store your page as a HTML file in your resources.

```
  // Create the UIWebView
  UIWebView *webView = [[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame] autorelease];

  // Add the UIWebView to our view  
  [self.view addSubview:webView];

  // Load the HTML document from resources
  NSString *pagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"legal" ofType:@"html"];
  NSURL *pageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pagePath];
  NSURLRequest *pageReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pageURL];
  [webView loadRequest:pageReq];
```